# Removing untracked files

Tags: node.js, git, npm, visual-studio-code

I am trying to remove `node_modules` untracked files from git status list, but to keep them in local repository.

Using:

- Visual Studio Code 1.0.0
- git version 2.8.2.windows.1
- Windows 7 64bit

I have tried running 
`git rm -r --cached node_modules`
but I get error `fatal: pathspec 'node_modules' did not match any files`

`git status` returns:

> On branch master
>   Untracked files:
>    (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
>
> ```
>    node_modules/
> ```
>
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

EDIT:

Issue is resolved. For reference, gitignore I'm using:
https://www.gitignore.io/api/visualstudiocode,visualstudio,node,windows,bower

Comment: It is not tracked, so `git rm` has no effect. Put node_modules in your .gitignore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a hidden file **.gitignore** to your root folder and add node_modules to that file

Comment: Have that already, generated from gitignore.io, with node_modules listed.

Comment: You can add any file in .gitignore which you want to keep in your  local system but do not want to commit

Comment: My bad, I named the file .ignore instead of .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

- if you want to be sure if an element is ignored or not:

  ```
  git check-ignore -v -- afileOrFolder
  ```
- the [`.gitignore`-generated file from gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/api/node) **does not always add the trailing '`/`' at the end of the folders to be ignored**.
  Adding the trailing '`/`' is considered a bast-practice.

It should be:

```
# Dependency directories
node_modules/
jspm_packages/
```

Not:

```
# Dependency directories
node_modules
jspm_packages
```

From the gitignore man page:

> If the pattern ends with a slash, it would only find a match with a directory.
>   In other words, `foo/` will match a directory foo and paths underneath it, but will not match a regular file or a symbolic link `foo` (this is consistent with the way how pathspec works in general in Git).